# A way to keep snapshots of data on a report, whilst also showing new data when the report is ran

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am creating a report using Report Builder and I wondered if there is a way to keep snapshots of a matrix table taken at a specific time, and have those snapshots appear every time the report is ran.

Explicitly, I have a report that will be ran at 7:30 am and only 7:30 am every day. In the report is a matrix table that shows the data that is in my SQL database exactly at 7:30 am on that particular day. When I run the report the next day, I want the data from yesterday to still be there, unchanged, and also the data from when the report is ran. I basically want to see how the data changes per day.

I can't find much about this problem, or even if it can be solved at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not really the job for the report service. if you want to keep old data, you have to generate it yourself and store it somewhere and then make the report read from that location

Comment: If you were on a *supported* version of SQL Server then temporal tables would make this trivial.

Comment: @ThomA I am, how would I go about this?

Comment: No, you'r not. SQL Server 2012 ran completely out of support *las year*, and ran out of mainstream support 6 years ag.